# Does gluon mobile (javafx) support woff and woff2 font type?

Tags: javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

I am trying to load woff and woff2 font type in my gluon mobile app using stylesheet. 
But at the app start I am getting following messafe

```
INFO: Could not load @font-face font [file:....Circular-Pro-Bold.woff]
```

Comment: Short answer NO.